# How to track memory allocation via DPDK API rte_malloc?

Tags: dpdk

Based on DPDK API documentation `rte_malloc_dump_stats` is said to ***Dump for the specified type to a file***. But neither custom application or `app/test/test_malloc.c` shares the desired result.

Expectation: for DPDK API rte_malloc, rte_calloc, and rte_zmalloc is created with `const char *type`. the stats for specific `const char *type` can be queried with `rte_malloc_dump_stats`

Current result: DPDK API rte_malloc_dump_stats gives overall heap usage, without any information about which "type" uses how much.

Question: Is there any other API available in DPDK to track the huge page malloc usage? Any DPDK patch would be useful?

Sample code flow:

```
/* with huge page */
rte_eal_init 

/* create memory location for various object type */
rte_malloc ("objecttype-1")
rte_malloc ("objecttype-2")
rte_malloc ("objecttype-3")
rte_malloc ("objecttype-4")

/* dump stats for object type - 1 */
rte_malloc_dump_stats ("objecttype-1")
```

My application calls rte_calloc, which calls few other internal subroutines and finally calls heap_alloc (in which "type" seems to be unsed).
heap_alloc(struct malloc_heap *heap, const char *type __rte_unused, size_t size, unsigned int flags, size_t align, size_t bound, bool contig). Heap alloc currently seems to ignore the "type" argument. How to track the heap memory usage?

Comment: The function heap_alloc is an internal static function, If you are intention is to track memory alloc and free done with the specific name passed to rte_malloc/rte_calloc/rte_zmalloc. I request to edit the question for clarity. There is a way to do the tracking based on name

Comment: Thank you for the response. How to track the mem allocation per type ? What APIs can the application use to alloc and what API to dump the stats ? [ rte_calloc with malloc_dump_stats - combo does not help to track per "type" allocation stats ]

Comment: thanks for update, there is no API in DPDK which does this automatically I can share the code snippet (that does not modify the library) what I used to achieve the same. Does that work for you?

Comment: Sure. This would help. Pls share. Let me check that and revert back.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the real question. please accept the change to acknowledge if this is intended question or not. It will make things easier to answer.

Comment: Sure. This question captures the intent. Thank you

Comment: updated with the answer for the intended question, Please review and if find it useful please accept and upvote to close the question.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. we will try the suggested approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observation is correct, currently DPDK API rte_malloc, rte_zalloc, rte_calloc discards the name field which is represented by first argument as `const char *type`. Hence dump or query with DPDK API rte_malloc_dump_stats does not return for specific `const char *type`.

There are a couple of workaround to this problem (without modifying the DPDK library), such as

1. rte_memzone_reserve creates a named area (which can be the desired type) as a repalcement.
2. rte_mempool_create_empty to create a named empty mempool.

both approaches have its disadvantages

1. memzone: is normally targeted for larger areas and called once, hence frequent calls to memzone_reserve for the small objects will have a performance impact. One has to also use `rte_memzone_walk` to iterate through the desired `const char *type`  to get the details too.
2. empty_mempool: expects all objects put into are of the same size, hence it is useful in places like creating a pool of reusable counters, or lists. But using `rte_mempool_lookup` has an easier way to access the pool for details like the number of elements, size and cached elements per core etc.

There is a much easier alternative by simply creating `Create a container to hold malloc|calloc|zalloc name, pointer and size using fb_arry`. on every successful allocation fetch an element holder from fb_array and update the details. major advantage of this approach is `fb_arry can be extended on huge page via rte_memzone_reserve`, which makes monitoring of `const char *type` with almost no modification.

Code Snippet:

```
struct rte_memzone *mptr = NULL;

struct elements {
    char name[256];
    void *ptr;
};

/* right after rte_eal_init */
mptr = rte_memzone_reserve_aligned("MALLOC_REGIONS",
            sizeof(struct rte_fbarray), SOCKET_ID_ANY,
            RTE_MEMZONE_2MB, 8);

/* create a wrapper or MACRO to insert details of each alloc with type field */
do
{
    ptr = rte_malloc(NULL, size_dataoibject, 0);
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return NULL;

    int index = rte_fbarray_find_next_free((struct rte_fbarray *)mptr->addr, 0);
    if (index < 0) {
        printf("fail in rte_fbarray_find_next_free %d", index);
        rte_free(ptr);
        return NULL;
    }

    return ptr;
} while(0);

/* in the data processing thread, invoke the MACRO/function*/
```

references:

1. [DPDK debug guide](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/howto/debug_troubleshoot.html)
2. [malloc monitor](https://github.com/vipinpv85/DPDK-APP_SAMPLES/tree/master/malloc-monitor)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. We will try the suggested approach.

Comment: [1] what is "1000" (last argt) in rte_memzone_reserve_aligned ? The API guide says that the last argt is alignment.
[2] where is "struct element" used ?
[3] every alloc and every free - needs to do insertion/deletion from fbarray ?
[4] The entire fbarray APIs indicate "rte experimental" - is it recommended to use those ? Usually we are not using the experimental APIs.
[5] Why not have hash tables - per "malloc group" - insert/remove - from hash table for alloc/delete. What is the advantage of using the fbarray ?
Kindly clarify. Thank your very much for the support.

Comment: the shared email with the request `Requesting to set up a meeting with the team (cisco), to better understand the ask?`